# python: looping from exception

Tags: python-2.7, try-catch, urllib2

I have the following code, which makes an http request using `urllib2`. The code is between try/except for catching an http error. At some point I'm getting an `urllib2.HttpError`. Im catching it, and I want to do the above code (outside the catch) n times before handling the exception in a different matter. Here is the following code with `goto .label` just to demonstrate what I want to do but didnt find how to do it.

```
recoveryTimes = 5
try:
            data = urllib.urlencode(values)     
            req = urllib2.Request(url, data)   
            label .request (this is where i want to jump after the exception)
            urllib2.urlopen(req)
            response = urllib2.urlopen(req)    
            the_page = response.read()  

except urllib2.HTTPError:
                if (recoveryTimes > 0):
                    goto .request
                else:
                    self.setUrllib2Proxy()
```

for summarization, If an http request if failing, I want to try again and again. Only after failing 'n' times, I want to go to the else statement.

Comment: You may consider using a [retying](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retrying) module.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a decorator for retry yoour block of code

```
import time
import math

def retry(tries, delay=1):
    '''Retries a function or method until it returns True.

    delay sets the initial delay in seconds. tries must be at least 0, and delay
    greater than 0.'''
    tries = math.floor(tries)
    if tries < 0:
        raise ValueError("tries must be 0 or greater")
    if delay <= 0:
        raise ValueError("delay must be greater than 0")
    def deco_retry(f):
        def f_retry(*args, **kwargs):
            mtries = tries
            rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
            while mtries > 0:
                if rv is True:
                    return True
                mtries -= 1
                time.sleep(delay)
                rv = f(*args, **kwargs)
            return False
        return f_retry
    return deco_retry
```

Make your code as method, they must return True  or False, and decorate it with previous code